# How to dynamically modify workbench.xmi during startup runtime-eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rcp, workspace, e4

Since user did some complex operation happened in my Eclipse Rcp Application, which causes some wrong setting happened in user's workspace, (with some projects existing in the workspace).

And when user start to run on the application in that "bad" workspace, the Eclipse RCP gui looks weird, and the existed projects can't opened properly.

After research, I found it's because of some wrong settings happened in workbench.xmi file located in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench, in the user's workspace.

A workaround is to manually change remove the wrong settings in workbench.xmi, or change to a new workspace and copy user's projects into the new workspace.

My question is how to dynamically identify the wrong setting workbench.xmi file located in user's workspace, so that I can change the content of workbench.xmi, during startup my Eclispe RCP application ? So that user don't need to do the manual workaround.

Comment: How can we answer this when you have told us anything about the 'wrong settings'?

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you very much for your quick reply.  The "wrong setting" is that Eclipse navigator overrides my custom navigator in my workbench.xmi file. I just found  a solution, after whole application finished startup in bad workspace,                                                         
I get the WorkbenchPage, and call `WorkbenchPage.resetPerspective();` then I got my custom navigator and all editors and viewer are recovered.